# Mysql - service table where I need all service provided by the client

Tags: mysql

I have a service table with the following column Snum, Cnum, Program, Sdate, and unit. The snum is the service number, cnum is the client number, program is the program they bill the service to and the number of units.

```
snum   cnum   program   sdate      unit
1      1      A         2018-03-01 1
2      1      B         2018-03-02 1
3      2      A         2018-03-04 2
4      2      D         2018-03-05 1
5      3      C         2018-03-24 3
```

Okay, I am trying to pull a list of all services provided to program `A` by `cnum`, but also any service provided by `cnum` to any other programs as well.
In the example above, I want to pull snum `1-4` but not `5`.

Comment: What does the output look like? Have you tried to write a query to do that? Post what you have tried even if it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself, restricting one of the tables to just `program = 'A'`.

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM service AS s1
JOIN service AS s2 ON s1.cnum = s2.cnum
WHERE s2.program = 'A';
```

You can also write this more intuitive with `WHERE ... IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM service
WHERE cnum IN (
    SELECT cnum
    FROM service
    WHERE program = 'A'
)
```